# How to conditionally check for author archive when is_author() fails to work because the author has no posts

Tags: archives, author

I am using the author archive to output user profiles, however the is_author() function only works if the author has a post.

If I visit an author archive page directly IE: /author/author-11, it has body classes "archive author author-11", so WordPress does know that this is an author archive page.

However using:

```
if ( is_author() ){

    //do stuff like hooking social share buttons

    }
```

only works if the author has posts.

How to check if we are on an author archive page, when the author has no posts?

EDIT: Adding additional code context (This code works only when an author has a post. It outputs social buttons at the top of the page.)

```
add_action ('get_header','wcr_social_buttons');

function wcr_social_buttons(){

    if ( is_author() ){

       echo "hello"; //for testing
        add_action ('genesis_before_loop','wcr_share_buttons' );

        }
}
    //Edit: added the rest of the code

     elseif (is_front_page() || is_post_type_archive()  || is_tax('local-info') || is_page(array())) {

     add_action ('genesis_after_loop','wcr_share_buttons');

}

function wcr_share_buttons(){
echo "hey"; //for testing
social_likes(  ) ; //social likes plugin
}
```

Comment: `is_author()` should work nonetheless. Please post the code in more context.

Comment: More code context added...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't something other than `is_author()`? Try to `echo` soemthing in place of that `add_action()`

Comment: And why are you piping that through two filters?

Comment: Thanks for that, echoing something else worked both in the add_action() and in the wcr_share_buttons() function. So something else is fishy with the social_likes() function.

Comment: I added additional code context. The two filters are because I'm using an elseif statement to hook to a different part of the theme. But I see now that I could just hook the social_likes function directly and get rid of the extra wcr_share_buttons() function. I'll have to talk to the plugin developer why social_likes() would only work when there are posts on an author archive page.

Comment: Are you sure that the author actuall exists. `is_author()` returns true even when an author don't have posts, but is returns false whenever the given author does not exists in database due to the page being directed to a 404 page

Comment: Yes, all the authors do exist. I can go to their absolute url and see each profile. is_author() works to hook many other functions including detailed profile information into each author's archive pages, it only seems to fail for one specific plugin.